# Computing Result on server side but session data not isolated per user

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Working on a web app where user takes test and they see their score at the end of the test.
I compute the user score on the server side. The problem is that, when a user take a test, it affect the score of another user taking another test. what i mean is if a user A takes a test, and a user B is taking a test also from another system, at the end of the day, user A sees user B result as his result. Really do not know what is wrong with the code. But below is my code for computing the user score

```
def Compute_UserScore(self, details, ques_no):
    try:
        if(HomePage.answer_.strip() == ""):
            self.response.write("""<script type = "text/javascript">
            alert("Dear User, You can not answer same answer twice.. Take test Again !");
            </script>""")
            self.redirect('/otherPages/subjectSelect.html')
        else:
            count = 0
            HomePage.ans_no = 0
            HomePage.unans_no = 0
            HomePage.correct_no = 0
            HomePage.wrong_no = 0
            HomePage.failed_ques = list()
            HomePage.answer_ = HomePage.answer_.strip()
            question_1 = HomePage.question_.split(" gcdc_split_format ")
            while (count != (ques_no)):
                user_answer = str(details[count]).strip().capitalize()
                real_answer = str(HomePage.answer_[count]).strip().capitalize()
                if (len(str(user_answer).strip()) == 1):
                    HomePage.ans_no = HomePage.ans_no + 1
                    if(user_answer.strip() == real_answer.strip()):
                        HomePage.correct_no = HomePage.correct_no + 1
                    else:
                        HomePage.wrong_no = HomePage.wrong_no + 1
                        HomePage.failed_ques.append(str("No. " + str(int((count + 1))) + "  " + str(question_1[count])))
                else:
                    HomePage.unans_no = HomePage.unans_no + 1
                count = count + 1
            HomePage.answer_ = ""
    except:
        self.redirect('/')
    return " "
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what your *HomePage* is but it seems to be a global variable or a package name.
Either one means that every user of your web app is sharing the same memory storage (variables) for test result.

This is not the right way to do it if you want to save all users' test results. You should have a way to identify different users (i.e. having a user sign in) so you can show different results for a different user, and save the results in a database or in a python dictionary.

Another way to do it is to save the results in cookie, the cookie data is saved on the client side, so it would be different for different users.

Comment: Hompage is a class. below is the fragment of the code             class HomePage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    percentage = None
    subject_answered = None
    username_ = None
    email_ = None
    super_date = None
    answer_ = " "
    question_ = " "
    failed_ques = list()
    wrong_no = 0
    correct_no = 0
    ans_no = 0
    unans_no = 0

Answer (score 0):

The attribute values are shared for HomePage and are getting written over each other. Instead you should create an instance of the class.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent people from seeing other people's answer, you'd need an identification system. A simple username/password combination will do. You can then make a simple DB table to store this, along with their scores. You didn't put Homepage up for us to see, so I couldn't tell how you instantiated it, or what the structure looks like, but you need an ID system.